# Can I use a hot water recirculation pump to mitigate risk of exterior wall pipe freeze?

Tags: pipe, freezing, circulator

We have a home in a cold location that is unoccupied during much of the cold season. (We're talking -30 F temperatures here.) It's well insulated and we keep it heated, but up in a far corner of the house, in a laundry room, the temperature can drop to about 10 deg less than the rest of the house (which we keep around 65).

The potential problem here is that the pipes for the washing machine run inside that exterior wall. Again, it's well insulated, but a 2x6" wall is only so thick, and I worry that pipe may freeze. The way we currently try to keep it warm isn't smart, IMO. There's an electric baseboard on that wall, and I set it to a spot where it keeps that room a minimum of 63-ish degrees. It kicks on for much of the winter, sucking a lot of juice, just in the hope that heating the drywall in front of those pipes will keep them above freezing when it's -30 or -40 outside.

I was pondering running a line from our boiler to a new register up there, when I realized **maybe I could run hot water directly through the at-risk pipes themselves.**

I wonder if running a hot-water recirculator designed for systems with no return line (as we have none) wouldn't be a smarter and more energy efficient solution. Something like this one: https://youtu.be/Jd0IsylW4Cc

There's a utility sink up there which would be a perfect spot to stick a bypass, and it's the furthest line in the house (and bonus, it's behind the shower we use, so it would save us on water not having to wait for that to heat up.) It's probably a run of 30 feet. If I understand things correctly, that would run the warm/hot water through both the hot/cold lines as programmable intervals. I figure a couple of times per hour would do the trick, and we have a pretty efficient (and low cost) water heater with a huge tank.

This would save me a ton of worry, and it would also let us heat the home to a lower temp (50s) without worrying about that one pipe run. (All the other pipes are inside walls or under the heated slab.) I imagine I could get system and my plumber to install for about $500, and between the excess fuel burned keeping the home extra warm just for this pipe, and running the baseboard as a backup, this would probably pay for itself in overall energy savings in a year or two.

Edit: FWIW, prior owner lived there for 2 decades without freezing up this pipe, but I don't know where they ran their temps and the baseboard all winter. (Pipe they ran into an unheated attached garage did burst -- that I have seen -- and it was disclosed during sale. I removed that line -- was to an unnecessary hose bib -- and capped the line in the interior wall.)

Comment: This isn't an answer, just a comment. I've dealt with frozen pipes that burst in my vacation home and it did a LOT of damage. Now, when we aren't there we turn off the water to the house to be safe.  In your case, given those very  low temps, I'd be winterizing it by turning off the water and use an air compressor to blow out all the lines. Then you could lower the temp without worry and save some energy bills.

Comment: Yeah, we turn off the pump and depressurize so if we do get a break, it's not a flood, but there are complications with winterizing it entirely that way, including that we visit it during the cold times so re-winterizing it several times a year isn't a great option. This really is the only line at risk under normal circumstances -- but a prolonged power outage would be trouble. We have a caretaker there weekly.

Comment: A prolonged power outage would scupper your recirc plan, too. You might consider, instead, putting valves on the supply lines for the washer in a warm area, then putting drain lines in. This way, you can shut off and drain _just_ the washer plumbing. This would allow you to use the water in the rest of the house whenever you needed to without impacting it. Or, if you need to do laundry, it's simple to shut off and drain just the pipes at risk. If there's no water in the pipe, it can't freeze no matter how cold it is or if the power's off.

Comment: Far more effective/efficient given the statements of the question to provide valves and drains to (easily) drain and blow clear this section of pipe during the at-risk unoccupied season.

Comment: There's not much chance of retrofitting a partial system shutoff and drain given that it's buried in walls and floors and what pipe is available in utility room also feeds the main bathrooms. Total power failure for days shuts everything down, for sure, but if that happens, (never seen one) draining entire system from the bottom is something caretaker can undertake. At-risk lines are highest and would empty first. Lower lines are under heated slab that would take a week or more to actually freeze. (Place has an unheated garage and that slab takes weeks to get below freezing.)

Comment: And as mentioned, we visit during that season, so a cycle of draining and blowing out the lines for every trip simply isn't practical. Can we just leave aside the perfect solution since it doesn't apply to the use case?

Comment: _I_ wouldn't consider a shut off and drain at the low point for the washer hookups to be that big a deal. Water will flow down hill all by itself so there's no need to blow water out of the lines (which would be a royal pain). But, it's your place. Sounds like you just want us to approve of your plan, which Ecnerwal has done in his [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/245958/34147), so you're good to go.

Comment: Depends on pipe layout, (sometimes the wall piping is not set up well to drain itself, so water remains trapped) but even if you do need to blow (or vacuum) it, the trick is merely to set it up so that's no big deal, and then it's just part of the 5 minutes before you leave and when you arrive, rather than being a huge hassle.

Comment: I would run new pipes not in the exterior wall, and abandon those pipes in the exterior wall.   Also, think about an Empire style or Williams style wall or floor furnace - generally nobody has heard of them in the snow belt, but they are a gas furnace that does not use any electricity at all - their external thermostat is powered by a thermocouple on the gas pilot light, and exhaust is powered by "hot air rises".  This has an efficiency cost, but if you have a more efficient furnace you can set its thermostat lower so it only runs when the main furnace is inoperative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would work, (so long as you have power and hot water.) Not the best solution, but it would work.